# Is that possible to add a value in a core data fetch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

Suppose I have this core data structure:

```
code
name
address
value
```

is that possible to add 100 to value during the fetch? I mean, to receive a fetch results where all values are their values on the database + 100?

I know I can enumerate all results after and change the value but I am wondering if there is a way to do that while I fetch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all a fetch can do is give you the literal contents of the persistent store. If you're fetching a managed object subclass you might consider adding a computed property as a category method that always returns the named field plus 100; if you're fetching dictionaries then you'll probably have to modify them yourself (which will be a hassle as they'll come back immutable).

Comment: That immutability is the reason why I have asked that. Thanks.